# Having trouble vertically centering an element

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

https://jsfiddle.net/93hjyhs8/

I'm trying to vertically center the text on the right, but having great difficulty finding a pure CSS solution that works in all browsers.

The height of the .block element should be dynamic and expand to the size of the tallest child element (currently .thing1).

Note, that if possible I would prefer to avoid hacks such as using tables, but feel free to post those kind of solutions regardless.

Also, why is the element not only at the bottom but also slightly nudged down?

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}
.thing1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.thing2 {
  background: red;
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <span class='thing1'></span><span class='thing2'>Hello world how are you today r u alrite m8 i think u r weak m8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/93hjyhs8/1/

add `vertical-align:middle` for both the `inline-block` elements

Comment: Knew it was a simple answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new awesome css **flexbox**,

```
.block {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

> Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3y41ot0b/

Comment: Very cool, but not the best browser support. Unfortunately here I needed an IE6 solution :(

Comment: may be helpful, http://designkarma.co.uk/blog/using-flexbox-now and http://www.sitepoint.com/are-we-ready-to-use-flexbox/